# AWS Lambda - get end point in handler

Tags: aws-lambda

How can I get the lambda end point in my handler code written in node.js after its deployment, so I can do the service registration?

Comment: what do you mean by endpoint? api endpoint that depends on the region? the ARN of your function? or do you have API Gateway in mind?

Comment: let me clarify. The cloundfromation will create a Gateway API in front of Lambda. I want to register the service (Gateway API HTTP end point)to a registrar for later service discovery when lambda is deployed. Does the Gateway API http end point have to be immutable?

Comment: You can use a custom domain name with your api gateway. This will give you a stable endpoint no matter how often you change your api gateway behind it. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html